# How to configure JMS on Glassfish v.3.1.1 to communicate between instances?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, cluster-computing

I am using Glassfish Open Source Edition v. 3.1.1 and I am trying to achieve structure like this: 
[Application schema](http://klkl.pl/jms.png)

I am using Message Driven Bean to receive Messages.

My manager receive tasks from web servlet. Then he publish task to topic.

I have a problem with receiving information from this topic from different instances.

For example if I send task on server (Port 8080) I will receive this task only on this instance. And If I send task to topic on instance 2(Port 28081), I will receive this task only on instance 2.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this possible to configure Glassfish in this way ?
2. Maybe there are some better solutions to this problem, any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

example: 2 instances in 1 cluster node on 1 machine

1. create connection factory  in Resources->JMS Resources-> Connection Factories and add properties AddressList=localhost:7676 and set target server (Admin Server)
2. create Topic in Resources->JMS Resources-> Destination resources and set target server
3. in cluster config set in Java Message Services  JMS Service Type: REMOTE

and each instance will receive a message.